# secuiring Microservices in ASP.NET Core + Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, microservices, token

I have more than 3 micro service, Main API that contient Identity and many other functionality, an EDM Micro-service ans another micro-service ... and i have angular as my front end.
for my main API and my angular everything going well from the security to token exchange between my angular and  service ...
Now here's my problem, i wanna secure my 2 other API suing my main API token because as i know angular can handle only with one token as header (or there's a solution ?).
i did a search throw the internet and i didn't something work with my requirement or my i miss something so excuse me, im not with micro-service.

- How can i secure my micro-service ?
- if i use identity ? how can handle the token from angular as i will have many token ?
  and im open for any another proposition ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can create a relationship and hierarchy for users and roles.
Let's consider 2 microservices, one is for the customer and the second one is for payment. If you want to access the endpoint of customer microservice to get/update/delete customer data, then you need to pass the appropriate roles in the HTTP header, and those roles need to bind to the user.

So consider **User A** as having **roles getCustomer,UpdateCustomer,deletecustomer**. U**ser A can access only the customer microservice endpoint**, not the Payment microservices endpoint.

Now where to configure this mapping and hierarchy?

you need to create/enhance(if you have a microservice) **Identity microservice** for this which will generate the token also maintain the relationship between user and roles.

endpoint will be like::

{identityMs}/createUser

{identityMs}/getUser

{identityMs}/getToken

This microservice will provide the access/security token which contains information like User and roles like below.

```
{
   "user":"A",
   "roles":[
             "getCustomer",
              "deleteCustomer"
           ]
}
```

Once a call is reached to microservice, we need to make to the Identity microservice for validation of roles, users, token expiration etc. If the token successfully gets validated, you can perform the operation on ms.

From the angular js application, you need to call, the Identity microservice endpoint bypassing the UserName to get the actual token with roles for that specific endpoint. And pass that token while calling the actual microservice.

If you want to call every endpoint, you can create only one user with all the roles of all microservices. In case you only need the Customer micorservice endpoint, you can create the new User with the specific role of Customer microservice and generate the token and call the Customer MS.